# django template url issue

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I have set up dynamic linking from a ListView which worked fine, but now that I am filtering the ListView any links from the template are appending the current url. Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
     path('list/<area>/', ProjectListView.as_view(), name='project-list'),
     path('project-create/',
          ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project-create'),
     path('<slug:slug>/update/', project_update_view, name='project-update'),
     path('search/', search, name='search'),
]
```

in the template my link looks like this:

```
    <h3><a href="{{ project.slug }}/update">{{ project.title }}</a></h3>
```

and I was hoping it would look here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/si/
```

but instead it is looking here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/si/list/All/
```

of which "list" was added to prevent other urls matching wrongly, which I can just add if necessary, and "All" which comes from a dynamic variable from the filter and will be one of 8 different strings.

How can I get this url to look at where I specified in the urls.py and not just append the current url?

UPDATE: adding view:

```
def project_update_view(request, slug):
    """
    project_update_view combines an update form with the update
history.
    """
    obj = Project.objects.get(slug=slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectUpdateForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.project = obj
        if form.is_valid():
            completed = form.cleaned_data['completed']
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            if completed is True:
                CategorySatisfied.objects.create(
                    project=obj, update_category=category)
            form.save()
            return redirect('project-list')
    else:
        form = ProjectUpdateForm()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "object": obj
    }
    return render(request, 'project_portal/project_update.html', context)
```

Comment: What did you use as redirect in the `project_update_view`?

Comment: Not certain that I managed to get that in there, see my updated question for the view.

Comment: Alastair nailed it, thank you as always for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a leading slash to the URL so that it is an absolute URL, otherwise it is treated as a relative URL.

```
<h3><a href="/{{ project.slug }}/update">{{ project.title }}</a></h3>
```

You can avoid errors like this if you use the `{% url %}` tag instead of hardcoding your URL.

```
<h3><a href="{% 'project-update' project.slug %}">{{ project.title }}</a></h3>
```

If you have an `app_name = 'yourapp'` in the app's `urls.py`, then change `'project-update'` to `'yourapp:project-update'` above.

Comment: You nailed it! will mark it solved in 6 minutes time.